# Potential concurrency issue while checking and updating a record in table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional, optimistic-locking

Here is the case,

A member has to redeem a token to access (unlock) a given item.  The relevant database tables are:

**Table 1**

```
Table MEMBER_BALANCE: MEMBER_ID, TOKEN_BALANCE
```

**Table 2**

```
Table UNLOCKED_ITEM: MEMBER_ID, DATE_UNLOCKED, ITEM_ID
```

Checks, or constraints, that I need to enforce are

1. TOKEN_BALANCE must be > 0 when the user tries to unlock an item, and
2. The user hasn't unlocked the same item before.

My gut inclination is to write a simple method in MemberService.java:

```
@Transactional
public void unlockItem(Member member, Item item){
    memberBalanceDAO.decrementBalance(member);
    itemDAO.unlockItem(member, item);
}
```

I've dealt with the second requirement by adding a `unique` constraint on `MEMBER_ID` / `ITEM_ID` pair on the `UNLOCKED_ITEM` table.

I think, the only thing I need to take care of would be, users trying to unlock many items at the same time, with `TOKEN_BALANCE` requirement not met. For example, `TOKEN_BALANCE` is 1, but the user clicks to unlock two items, virtually, at the same time.

Below is my `MemberBalanceDAO.decrementBalance` method:

```
@Transactional
public void decrementBalance(Member member) {
    MemberBalance memberBalance = this.findMemberBalance(member);
    if (memberBalance.getTokens() >= 1) {
        memberBalance.setTokens(memberBalance.getTokens() - 1);
        this.save(memberBalance);
    } else {
        throw new SomeCustomRTException("No balance");
    }
}
```

I don't think this protects me from the `TOKEN_BALANCE` = 1 usecase. I'm worried about with multiple unlock requests at the same time.  If the balance is 1, I could get two calls to `decrementBalance()` at the same time both committing the balance to 0, but then also two successful calls to `itemDAO.unlockItem(...)` as well, right?

**How should I implement this?**  Should I set the service level method's transaction to `isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE`?  Or is there a cleaner/better way to approach this?

Comment: Oh, after I posted this question I found something relevant from the 'Related' section.  Should I be using   @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) for the decrementBalance method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather suggest you to introduce `version` column in `member_balance` table. Refer to the docs, [Optimistic Locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic).

As you mentioned that you couldn't modify the schema; you can go with versionless optimistic locks, [explained here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic-versionless-dirty).

Or you might like to go for pessimistic locking, [explained here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-jpa-query-hints). Then, you can modify your method, `decrementBalance()`, to fetch the member balance there, don't use `findMemberBalance()`. For example,

```
@Transactional
public void decrementBalance(Member member) {
    MemberBalance memberBalance = entityManager.find(
        MemberBalance.class, member.id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE,             
        Collections.singletonMap( "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 200 ) //If not supported, the Hibernate dialect ignores this query hint.
    );
    if (memberBalance.getTokens() >= 1) {
        memberBalance.setTokens(memberBalance.getTokens() - 1);
        this.save(memberBalance);
    } else {
        throw new SomeCustomRTException("No balance");
    }
}
```

**NB:** It might not work as it is; it's just to provide you some hints.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to modify the schema.  I'm in need of a pure programmatic solution.

Comment: Updated my answer, accordingly.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up implementing something very similar in the end.  Marking answer as accepted!